# prevent jQuery post request to fires mulitple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have a web shop where users can add products to there cart with one button, so they stay on the catalog page (where all products are listed). I do this by using jQuery and ajax. The weird thing is that when I press the button all forms will be submitted. This is not what I want!

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this),
            formdata = $form.serialize(),
            url = $form.attr('action');

        $.post(url, formdata);
    });
});
```

I understand I can't use a single class for this, since this will submit them all, but ids are not useful since I can have over 50 products on a page and that would be a lot of duplicated work.

So are there any solutions for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this looks fine... there is some other problem in you code

Comment: Check the other links on your page/form, add onclick="return false" to stop page reload/post.

Comment: It sounds like you've got one <form> for each product on your page, which would be an unusual way to handle this. You should be able to add an onclick handler to your 'Add' buttons, which will call a function passing in the Id of the product you want to add. You could then use this function to make the Ajax call.

Comment: Please post your HTML structure. Javascript code looks fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6ahs90Lt/.  No problem with the code you provided..

Comment: Are your per-product forms also added dynamically to the page?

Comment: Well I made the stupid mistake to use a foreach loop and add that jquery in for each product, so it would do the call mulitple times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show *should* work in isolation, so either your code is not being hit (due to an error on the page), or it is not connecting to the per-product forms (e.g. if they are also loaded dynamically).

If the forms are loaded dynamically, as I suspect they may be, then you need to use a *delegated event handler*, attached to a non-changing ancestor of the forms (`document` is the default)

e.g.:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this),
            formdata = $form.serialize(),
            url = $form.attr('action');

        $.post(url, formdata);
    });
});
```

it works by listening for the `submit` event to bubble up to the ancestor, *then* applies the jQuery `form` selector, *then* applies the function to any matching elements that caused the event, so will work on forms added to the page dynamically.

**If this is not the case, please provide the rest of your code and a sample of the page's HTML (from a browser save-as, not source).**

Answer (score 0):

When you build your product list, you could add an attribute to each button. Something like this should work:

```
<button data-productid='ABC123' onclick='addToCart(this)'>Add</button>

<script>
    function addToCart(btn) {
        var productId = $(btn).data('productid');
        // do ajax call, using productid
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think you just need another parameter, e.g. the ID of the current product**. So you will be able to do something like :

```
$(function() {
    $('.add-cart-form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this),
            productId = $(this).attr('data-product-id'), // Assuming you add the ID in your view
            formdata = $form.serialize() + '&productId=' + productID,
            url = $form.attr('action');

        $.post(url, formdata);
    });
});
```

Then, **you have to retrieve the productId parameter**, that will only return the current product.